# How to open and copy value to a new sheet when its not active?

Tags: vba, excel

I have copied a value from one sheet and trying to paste it in another sheet. The problem is the way I'm opening the second sheet. I have to keep the Excel sheet open and then use the activate method to open the second sheet and paste it. Is there any other way where the sheet can be opened directly through the given path or something?

```
Dim FindV As Range
Dim col, col1 As Long
Dim FAV, CC As String

//Relevant Working Code present here//

Selection.Copy
Windows("DS.xlsx").Activate
Set FindV = Range("A1:Z100").Find(What:="Dec Rel", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
FAV = FindV.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
ActiveCell = Range(FAV).Offset(0, 1)
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

`FindV.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False`

a line below Set FindV and you wouldn't need the rest